# Change default behaviour for keyboard input

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to disable the default behavior of the WPF `DataGrid` UI control, that on pressing the enter button on a specific cell, the focus moves automatically to the next cell. It should just commit the edited new data, but not move to the next cell.

I found a workaround by installing a `PreviewKeyDown` handler and using two `MoveFocus` calls. Without that workaround (only with the `e.Handled = true` statement), the edited data will not committed properly (the cell will stay in the editing mode infinitely).

XAML:

```
<DataGrid PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"... </DataGrid>
```

Handler:

```
    private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && uiElement != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Left));
            uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Right));
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help me to find a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `CommitEdit()` method to commit the data:

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        ((DataGrid)sender).CommitEdit();
    }
}
```